# VMWare ESX: Intermittent network connectivity when guests are on same host

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-esx

- ESXi 5.5.0, Build: 2403361 on Dell R620 Servers
- 2 phys servers, 1 SAN, 15+ VMs

Issue: In some cases, when guest A and B are on the same phys server, network communication between the two is intermittent or essentially down. All other networking is OK.

We have seen this from Win->Win (Win2012->Win2012 and Win8.1->Win2012), and from Win2012->LinuxCentOS. We do not think it has anything to do with the OS.

The problem is immediately resolved by moving one of the guests (say A) to the other physical server. Everything instantly works.

There are no other networking issues.

Where do we start to dig into this?

Comment: What version and BUILD NUMBER of VMware ESXi are you running?

Comment: @ewwhite OP enhanced. Thank you for pushing for an appropriate clarification.